# Swift UI test, how to check if a cell has an imageview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, uitest

In UI test, I can get the first cell using this code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()

app.launch()

let tablesQuery = app.tables

let cell = tablesQuery.children(matching:.any).element(boundBy: 0)
```

How to check if that cell contains a imageview ?

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5

Give the cell's ImageView an accessibility identifier first either in storyboard or `ViewDidLoad`

[image: Storyboard Accessibility ID]

```
func testIsImageViewNil() {
    let imageView = app.images["PhotosCollectionViewController.ImageCell.ImageView"]
    XCTAssertNotNil(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public func hasImageViewInside(_ cell: UITableViewCell) -> Bool {
    for child in cell.subviews {
        if let _ = child as? UIImageView {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Won't work if the imageView is more than a level deep, which it probably is, provided it was correctly added to `cell.contentView`.

Comment: @ConnorNeville You're right but it's not too hard to make it recursive. The idea's the same.

Comment: You don't have access to this when querying in a UI test right?

Answer (score 0):

```
        for viw in cell.contentView.subviews {
        if ((viw as? UIImageView) != nil) {
            print("123")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.images.element.assert(\.exists)
```

Instead of `.assert(\.exists)` you can do what you want with this XCUIElement of image view

Answer (score -1):

```
  for case let imageView as UIImageView in cell.contentView.subviews  {
      if imageView.tag == 1001 {
         imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myCustomImage")
      }
  }

  //OR Altervnatively


  cell.contentView.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }.forEach { imageView in
      if imageView.tag == 1001 {
         imageView.image = UIImage(named: "myCustomImage")
      }
  }
```